# How to find multiple starting letters in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to research multiple starting references in a list of Ids and set a cell as "yes" if the ID contains the wanted STARTING letters.

This is what I have for now:

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({"AUD","AZ","BURD"},$D2)),"YES","")
```

However this returns me yes if the cell contains the letters, but I want it only for starting letters

so I want **AUD**RTY to be "YES" but
   RT**AUD**FR to not return anything

I have found a solution with `IF(LEFT("AUD",3),"YES","")` however the letters I look for don't always have the same size.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIF() with wildcards:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($D2,{"AUD*","AZ*","BURD*"})),"YES","")
```

If any are present at the beginning it will return `1` to the criteria, which IF will see as True and return `YES`.  Otherwise it will return `0` and the IF will return an empty string.

Comment: Thank you it's perfect!